# Is there an encryption algorithm that allows checking whether source contains substring or not?

Tags: encryption

I'm looking for an encryption algoritm that allows to check for substring inside the source. It doesn't matter where the substing is. Just check for its existence given only encrypted text with a private key. So it should look like this:

```
enc = encrypt(src, key)
isthere(enc, substr)
```

Comment: If this were possible, you can get the whole plaintext by trying different "contains", without knowing the key. Such an encryption would be considered broken. The whole purpose of encryption is to prevent what you're trying, without decrypting first.

Comment: I don't think so. I mean the source text is big and has many repetitions so wouldn't efficiently brute it. It's not like a password of 5 chars, no, it's 1mb plain text.

Comment: Repetitions in the plaintext don't mean repetitions in the ciphertext. In fact, in a good encryption, the ciphertext **must** be indistinguible from random garbage, but your request explicitly ask for patterns in it. See the [ECB penguin](https://www.google.com/search?q=ecb+penguin) for why it's a bad idea. The [Caesar cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) allows this, and both things are considered broken and unsecure. The proper way to fulfill your requirement (and keep the whole thing secure) is to decrypt the text and search the plain text normally.